# Passando dados em javascript

Tags: javascript, html5

Seguinte, como eu posso fazer para passar dados entre dois arquivos com javascript?
Exemplo:

Arquivo1:

```
<script>
var dado = 'dado';
</script>
```

Arquivo2:

```
<script>
alert (dado);
</script>
```

Comment: São dois arquivos HTML diferentes?

Comment: Sim @bfavaretto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tens de ter em consideração 2 coisas:

- que ambas estejam no mesmo escopo (global ou comum)
- que a variável seja defenida antes do `alert();`. Ou seja esse código carregado primeiro.

Se não estiverem no mesmo escopo podes usar um objeto global para essa variável ser acessível:

Arquivo1:

```
<script>
window.dado = 'dado';
</script>
```

Arquivo2:

```
<script>
alert(window.dado);
</script>
```

Se estiveres a usar páginas HTML diferentes podes usar a [API do `localstorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) e usar `localstorage`em vêz do exemplo com `window` que dei em cima.

**Exemplo** onde escreve para o localstorage: http://jsfiddle.net/hL4dzhpa/
**Exemplo** onde lê do localstorage: http://jsfiddle.net/qn0umtfu/

Comment: para criar uma variável js global tenho que declarar window.variável?

Comment: @GustavoSevero sim. A outra maneira é omitindo `var` na declaração da variável mas isso é incorreto e dá dores de cabeça no debug.

Comment: @Sergio Se a variável for declarada no próprio escopo global, com `var`, ela também será global. Mas globais não resolvem o problema posto na pergunta.

Comment: @bfavaretto verdade, ambas :)

Comment: Resumindo, coloco window.variável e ela poderá ser acessada por qualquer arquivo do site ou sistema, correto?

Comment: @GustavoSevero sim!

Comment: Valeu pela ajuda @Sergio.

Comment: @GustavoSevero bom que pude ajudar.