# Como compartilhar funções entre arquivos javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho dois arquivos `JavaScript`.

**arquivo1.js**

```
function teste()
{
alert("fui chamado!");
}
```

No **arquivo2.js** eu gostaria de ter acesso a função `teste()` do **arquivo1.js** sem precisar fazer a referencia dentro do `HTML`.

Isso é possível?

Comment: Você pode usar um gerenciador de módulos, como [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/). Isso vai exigir que você altere o arquivo 1 para que fique compatível.

Comment: Parecida ou duplicada de: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/63389/129 ?

Comment: Desculpe @Sergio mas o link que você mostrou é uma boa alternativa para quem quer criar uma variável universal por exemplo, mas no meu caso, quero poder controlar qual arquivo terá acesso as funções do outro.

Comment: @bfavaretto você teria algum exemplo de uso em português?

Comment: Não tenho nada pra recomendar, mas o Google traz vários tutoriais. Este aqui parece um dos mais completos: http://www.devmedia.com.br/padronizacao-com-iife-amd-e-requirejs/31031 (aviso: não li, não garanto a qualidade).

Comment: Por não fazer referencia no HTML você exclui a possibilidade criar a referencia dinamicamente? Você pode adicionar o script **arquivo1.js** criando uma tag `<script>` no **arquivo2.js** e inserindo-a dinamicamente na página.

Comment: @MarcusVinicius Isso é possível, mas é preciso esperar o outro arquivo carregar antes de ter acesso às funções dentro dele (o carregamento é assíncrono).

Comment: Sim, @bfavaretto. É possível fazer um script "esperar" o outro usando callbacks no evento `onload` do elemento script criado.

Comment: @MarcusVinicius Aliás, é basicamente isso que o RequireJS faz :)

Comment: @JedaiasRodrigues: um tempo atrás eu "caçava" a função dentro do outro arquivo via xmlhttprequest usando um php de intermediário que retornava a função como String para ser executada como código. Na época tive problemas de compatibilidade, talvez as coisas estejam melhores hoje. Será um ótimo recurso para desenvolver em JavaScript a fundo!

Comment: Obrigado a todos pela ajuda, gostei muito da resposta postada pelo @MarcusVinicius mas infelizmente agora estou com problemas justamente na questão do assíncrono.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode fazer o carregamento dinâmico do script, criando uma tag `script`e inserindo-a na página. Por exemplo:

**Arquivo1.js**

```
function Script1() {
    this.DigaOla = function() {
        alert("Sou do script 1");
    }
};
```

**Arquivo2.js**

```
 function loadScript(url, callback) {    
     var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
     var script = document.createElement('script');
     script.type = 'text/javascript';
     script.src = url;    
     script.onreadystatechange = callback;
     script.onload = callback;

     head.appendChild(script);
 }

 $(document).ready(function() {
    loadScript("Arquivo1.js", function() {               
        var s = new Script1();
        s.DigaOla();
    });
 });
```

Comment: Só existe um problema @MarcusVinicius pois se eu acrescentar algo após o loadScript, como [nessa linha](https://github.com/Jedarc/horariofacil/blob/master/www/controllers/turmasController.js#L26) a mesma é executada antes da função ser finalizada! Nesse caso, o que fazer?

Comment: Não tem muito o que fazer senão colocar todo o código como callback do `loadDependency` que vc criou.  [Fiz um fork do seu código](https://github.com/Jedarc/horariofacil/blob/368542b809f403a6baa6332ad29f6116a71c606a/www/controllers/turmasController.js), dá uma olhada.

Comment: Muito obrigado meu amigo, poderia ter feito uma proposta de alteração para ficar registrado sua autoria. Com o fork infelizmente não consigo manter seus créditos.

Comment: Sem problemas, se quiser faco o pull request.

Comment: Por favor @MarcosVinicius irei me sentir melhor se fizer o pull request. Grato mais uma vez.

Comment: Tá feito, obrigado por me deixar contribuir. Se precisar de ajuda estou a disposição.

Answer (score 4):

A forma mais simples é incluir o arquivo1 antes do arquivo2 no seu HTML:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="arquivo1.js"></script>
    <script src="arquivo2.js"></script>
</head>
```

Todas as globais definidas no arquivo1 serão visíveis no arquivo2.

Uma maneira um pouco mais limpinha de fazer isso é escrever o arquivo1 de forma que apenas uma global seja exportada:

```
var LIB = {};

(function(){

   var msg = "fui chamado";

   var funcao_interna(){
       alert("oi");
   }

   LIB.teste = function(){
       alert(msg);
   }

   LIB.teste2 = funcao_interna;
}());
```

E no arquivo2 você faz

```
LIB.teste();
```

Esse `(function(){ ... }())` é uma "função imediatamente invocada" e é um truque que se usa em Javascript para controlar o escopo das variáveis. Todas as variáveis e funções declaradas ali dentro, como `msg` e `funcao_interna` não serão visíveis do lado de fora.

---

Outra maneira que você pode escrever é assim:

```
var LIB = (function(){

    function teste(){ alert("chamou") }

    return {
       teste:teste
    }
}());
```

Comment: Isso seria o mesmo que `window.LIB = (function(){ /* funções */ })();`?

Comment: pensei a mesma coisa que o @re22

Comment: @re22: Mais ou menos. Se você retornar um objeto com as funções exportadas da IIFE aí funciona (veja a minha edição)